# What exactly do these hexadecimal numbers represent in the LLDB output?

Tags: ios, debugging, lldb

After an exception is thrown, when using LLDB, I get this type of message in the in the Xcode output window:

```
*** First throw call stack:
(**0x1ea3012 0x1bb0e7e 0x1f2e4bd 0x1e92bbc**
```

My question is, what exactly do those hexadecimal numbers represent? Is that an address of a stack frame on the call stack? I'm really looking for correct terminology here.

Answer (score 2):

That's not output from lldb, it's output from your program (or a UIKit/AppKit/Foundation call you made).  Those look like code addresses in a 32-bit process -- something is trying to show you the call stack (a backtrace) of when an exception was thrown, I'd guess.  You can find what functions these are with the `image lookup` ("`im loo`" is the shortest unique form) lldb command.  For instance, a function in your own app might look like

```
(lldb) im loo -a 0x0009b92a
      Address: opengltest[0x0000b92a] (opengltest.__TEXT.__text + 514)
      Summary: opengltest`main + 514 at main.m:64
```

or a function in a system framework might look like

```
(lldb) im loo -a 0x310073d4
      Address: UIKit[0x2fe343d4] (UIKit.__TEXT.__text + 299972)
      Summary: UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1136
```

You can also add the `-v` (`--verbose`) option to `image lookup` - if this is a frame with debug information (a frame in your own app), lldb can print a lot of additional information about your function.